# How to solve $1 = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} x^{-p-1}$?

Tags: analysis, power-series

As the title says, I am trying to solve the equation
$$1 = \sum_{p \text{ prime}} x^{-p-1}$$
and I'm not really sure where to begin. I got this from an exercise in a book and apparently there is a unique positive solution. If it helps, the more general form of this is for any set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, solve
$$1 = \sum_{s \in S} x^{-s-1}.$$
Even some ideas of where to look would be great.

Comment: That there is a unique positive solution is clear, but that there exists a formula for this solution is quite dubious.

Comment: From what book is this?  What exercise number and page number?

Comment: It is Exercise 4.3.7 on page 117 in Douglas Lind's _Introduction to Symbolic Dynamics and Coding_. I was searching for something related and this came up on Google books. I haven't had time to actually get the book yet.

Comment: The exercise in Lind-Marcus does not ask to compute the unique positive solution.

Comment: @Did: I know it doesn't explicitly say that, but it asks to compute the entropy to two decimal places. Since it asks this in the same question where it presents the above formula, I reasoned that you were expected to use this. I know ways of approximating the entropy, but that's not what it asks. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Did: How did you see the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: @Nilan The RHS is a decreasing function of $x$.